# how to match an array value by it's key in a key value pair elasticsearch array?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have an array of `key value` pairs. Is it possible to exact match value of `key` & then do a check on it's `value`'s range value?

Example: In below doc `oracle_props` is an array with name, value pairs. I need to check if it has `"oracle_cursors"` key and then check if it's value is less than 1000.

```
GET /eg/message/_percolate
{
   "doc": {
      "client": {
         "name": "Athena",
         "version": 1,
         "db": {
            "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
            "oracle_props": [
               {
                  "@name": "open_cursors",
                  "@value": 4000
               },
               {
                  "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                  "@value": 1
               },
               {
                  "@name": "CREATE_PERMISSION",
                  "@value": "Y"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Below is my percolator.

I also need to check the following so that it gives back `3` as my result

1. "client.name" must be "Athena"
2. "client.db.@type" must be "Oracle" then only go ahead and check below points
3. "client.db.oracle_props.@name" field is not found
4. check if it has "oracle_cursors" key and then check if it's value is < 1000

1 & 2 are and operations and any of 3 or 4 satisfies it should result `3`. I need help with point 4, below is my query. Also please suggest if there is a better way.

```
PUT /eg/.percolator/3
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "or": [
               {
                  "missing": {
                     "field": "client.db.oracle_props.@name"
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "client.name": "Athena"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "client.db.@type": "Oracle"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Update**

Can I have something like below

```
{
     "match": {
                    "client.db.oracle_props[name='open_cursors'].value": 4000
                 }
              }
```

**More tries**

I followed [elasticsearch nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) and changed the mapping to [nestedtype](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) by re-indexing. Can anyone find problem why am i getting `nested: NullPointerException;`?

```
PUT /eg/.percolator/3
{
   "nested" : {
        "path" : "client.db.oracle_props",
        "score_mode" : "avg",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    {
                        "match" : {"client.db.oracle_props.@name" : "open_cursors"}
                    },
                    {
                        "range" : {"client.db.oracle_props.@value" : {"lt" : 4000}}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

mapping change

```
...
"properties": {
               "@type": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "oracle_props": {
                   "type" : "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "@name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "@value": {
                        "type": "long"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's get into it:

1. You seem to map your nested path wrong, `oracle_props` is a child item of `db` in your example document, but not in your mapping, where it appears directly as child of your root.
2. You are mapping `oracle_props.@value` as `long`, but assign a text `Y` to it at the `CREATE_PERMISSION` nested doc
3. You query for `range lt 4000`, which **excludes** 4000, `lte` would fit for you

I didn't get your requirement for the missing value, hence I skipped that.

To get you to the right path, I has to simplify it a bit (since I couldn't follow all the mess in your question, sorry)

I'm not going into percolation either, and renamed everything to twitter/tweet, since this was easier for me to copy from my examples.

1) Create empty index "twitter"

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/'
```

2) create geo_point mapping for the actual "tweet"

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping' -d '
{
    "tweet": {
        "properties": {
            "db": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "@type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "oracle_props": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "@name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "@value": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

3) Let's check if the mapping was set

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping?pretty=true'
```

4) Post some tweets, with nested data

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    "name": "Athena",
    "version": 1,
    "db": {
        "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
        "oracle_props": [
            {
                "@name": "open_cursors",
                "@value": 4000
            },
            {
                "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                "@value": 1
            },
            {
                "@name": "CREATE_PERMISSION",
                "@value": "Y"
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

5) Query nested only

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search -d '{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "db.oracle_props",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "db.oracle_props.@name": "open_cursors"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "db.oracle_props.@value": {
                                    "lte": 4000
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

6) Query "Athena" and "Oracle"

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search -d '{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "match" : {"tweet.name" : "Athena"}
                },
                {
                    "match" : {"tweet.db.@type" : "Oracle"}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

7) Combine the former two queries

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search -d '{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "match" : {"tweet.name" : "Athena"}
                },
                {
                    "match" : {"tweet.db.@type" : "Oracle"}
                },
                {
                    "nested" : {
                        "path" : "db.oracle_props",
                        "score_mode" : "avg",
                        "query" : {
                            "bool" : {
                                "must" : [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "db.oracle_props.@name": "open_cursors"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "db.oracle_props.@value": {
                                                "lte": 4000
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

Results as

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 2.462332,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "twitter",
                "_type": "tweet",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 2.462332,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Athena",
                    "version": 1,
                    "db": {
                        "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
                        "oracle_props": [
                            {
                                "@name": "open_cursors",
                                "@value": 4000
                            },
                            {
                                "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                                "@value": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "@name": "CREATE_PERMISSION",
                                "@value": "Y"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also if I assign `oracle_props.value` mapping as `string` range will not work on `long` but `string` and I need to do a range match and value also contains string. Is there any way to ignore `string` in such case?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, sorry.

Comment: @AbhishekSimon -  do a multi-type field.  Make one of them a long,  and one a String.  This will make it index the proper tokens for string contains,  and the long value compare.   See, http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html

Comment: @AndyPryor & Thorsten: Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Thorsten: Even I missed one of the condition. It's about `missing` field `"db.oracle_props.@name": "open_cursors"`. So it's like a recommendation. If `open_cursor` is not found, or it's value is less than 4000 then suggest a recommendation, which is why I was using percolator, in your case result should match your `twitter result`. Can you help?

Comment: I'm bot sure if I understand you correctly. You might simply want to move the `open_cursors` part from `bool: must` to `bool: should`?

Comment: I'll put this in a new question and will explain the problem with your twitter example. Please [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817965/how-to-check-missing-key-in-a-nested-type-elasticsearch-object)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Nested Document.  See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html

Comment: Thanks I am able to solve my problem with Thorsten's solution

Comment: @AbhishekSimon  Cool,  yeah sorry didn't have time to do a full solution,  but Thorsten's looks good.  The gist of it is, without nested types it's all flat in the index.

Comment: Can you please check a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817965/how-to-check-missing-key-in-a-nested-type-elasticsearch-object)