# How to check missing key in a nested type elasticsearch object?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a case where I collect some general info & db information (db2, oracle, sybase, informix) in key value pairs json format doc.

I also have some rules to check whether the above doc satisfies a particular rule, if satisfied give back that particular doc for analysis as a result.

here is the doc

```
PUT /twitter/tweet/1
{
    "name": "Athena",
    "version": 1,
    "db": {
        "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
        "oracle_props": [
            {
                "@name": "open_cursors",
                "@value": 4000
            },
            {
                "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                "@value": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and this is it's mapping

```
PUT /twitter/tweet/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
      "db": {
         "type": "object",
         "properties": {
            "@type": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "oracle_props": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "@name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "@value": {
                     "type": "long"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Rule criteria**

List out docs where tweet with `name Athena` and a `Oracle database` has `opencursors less than recommendaed value 4000` or when `opencursors is not present`.

So the above doc `/twitter/tweet/1` should come back as a result only if the following matches.

1. If (name == "Athena") && (db.@type contains "Oracle" keyword)
2. and (if (("open_cursors" @value < 4000) or ("open_cursors" not found under "db.oracle_props.@name")

below is the search query which matches above doc but is missing the last condition **(display doc "/twitter/tweet/1" even when "open_cursors" key is missing under "db.oracle_props.@name")**

```
GET /twitter/tweet/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "tweet.name": "Athena"
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "tweet.db.@type": "Oracle"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "db.oracle_props",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "db.oracle_props.@name": "open_cursors"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "range": {
                                 "db.oracle_props.@value": {
                                    "lt": 4001
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": 1
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give it another go, referencing your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690293/how-to-match-an-array-value-by-its-key-in-a-key-value-pair-elasticsearch-array) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690293/how-to-match-an-array-value-by-its-key-in-a-key-value-pair-elasticsearch-array/24762956#24762956).

I'll set up some example documents, that should or should not match correctly regarding my comments, if I understood your demands right:

```
// All good, should match
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    "name": "Athena",
    "version": 1,
    "db": {
        "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
        "oracle_props": [
            {
                "@name": "open_cursors",
                "@value": 4000
            },
            {
                "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                "@value": 1
            },
            {
                "@name": "CREATE_PERMISSION",
                "@value": "Y"
            }
        ]
    }
}'

// open cursors missing, should match
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/2' -d '{
    "name": "Athena",
    "version": 1,
    "db": {
        "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
        "oracle_props": [
            {
                "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                "@value": 2
            },
            {
                "@name": "CREATE_PERMISSION",
                "@value": "N"
            }
        ]
    }
}'

// open_cursors less than 4000, should match
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/3' -d '{
    "name": "Athena",
    "version": 1,
    "db": {
        "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
        "oracle_props": [
            {
                "@name": "open_cursors",
                "@value": 2134
            },
            {
                "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                "@value": 6
            },
            {
                "@name": "CREATE_PERMISSION",
                "@value": "N"
            }
        ]
    }
}'

// Different name, shouldn't match
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/4' -d '{
    "name": "Alexandroupolis",
    "version": 1,
    "db": {
        "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
        "oracle_props": [
            {
                "@name": "open_cursors",
                "@value": 4000
            },
            {
                "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                "@value": 1
            },
            {
                "@name": "CREATE_PERMISSION",
                "@value": "Y"
            }
        ]
    }
}'

// open_cursors more than 4000, shouldn't match
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/5' -d '{
    "name": "Athena",
    "version": 1,
    "db": {
        "@type": "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 64bit",
        "oracle_props": [
            {
                "@name": "open_cursors",
                "@value": 6500
            },
            {
                "@name": "USER_ROLE_PRIVS_COUNT",
                "@value": 1
            },
            {
                "@name": "CREATE_PERMISSION",
                "@value": "Y"
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

Hence we've got 3 documents (`ID 1,2,3`) that should be returned.

The solution that I've found seems quite complicated, maybe someone else can provide an easier way to solve this?

I've set up a [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html), in order to be able to use an [`OR` filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-filter.html)

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                /* Set up two conditions */
                "or" : [
                    /* First */
                    {
                        /* Check for open_cursors AND value < 4000 */
                        "bool" : {
                            "must" : [
                                /* Same nested query as in other questions answer */
                                {
                                    "nested" : {
                                        "path" : "db.oracle_props",
                                        "filter" : {
                                            "bool" : {
                                                "must" : [
                                                    {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "db.oracle_props.@name": "open_cursors"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "range": {
                                                        "db.oracle_props.@value": {
                                                            "lte": 4000
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    /* OR */
                    {
                        "bool" : {
                            /* watch out: negation, this MUST NOT be found*/
                            "must_not" : [
                                {
                                    "nested" : {
                                        "path" : "db.oracle_props",
                                        "filter" : {
                                            "bool" : {
                                                /* We do not want open_cursors to be in the nested document */
                                                "must" : [
                                                    {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "db.oracle_props.@name": "open_cursors"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            /* the query for the non-nested things */
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "match" : {"tweet.name" : "Athena"}
                        },
                        {
                            "match" : {"tweet.db.@type" : "Oracle"}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Return documents 1,2 and 3.

Update:
This is a simpler solution and should work, too. Thanks @TuanHuynh

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                /* Set up two conditions */
                "or" : [
                    /* First */
                    {
                        "nested" : {
                            "path" : "db.oracle_props",
                            "filter" : {
                                "bool" : {
                                    "must" : [
                                        {
                                        "term": {
                                            "db.oracle_props.@name": "open_cursors"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "db.oracle_props.@value": {
                                                "lte": 4000
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    /* OR */
                    {
                        "nested" : {
                            "path" : "db.oracle_props",
                            "filter" : {
                                "bool" : {
                                    /* We do not want open_cursors to be in the nested document */
                                    "must" : [
                                        {
                                        "term": {
                                            "db.oracle_props.@name": "open_cursors"
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            /* the query for the non-nested things */
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "match" : {"tweet.name" : "Athena"}
                        },
                        {
                            "match" : {"tweet.db.@type" : "Oracle"}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: @Thorsten, why would we need a bool.must before a nested filter? Could we just use nested filter right away after an OR filter?

Comment: Thank you, it should work without that, you are right. I've updated the answer.